# Need to convert List<E> to an Element

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist, element

I am passing in two lists of element E and want to insert one of the lists into the other at a specified index. I get the error "List cannot be converted to E" and I am unsure how to convert the element. Should I perhaps try something different than .add() or is it possible to convert an element so it will work with the .add() method?

I need to return a List for the other method I am calling this from.

**Edit:** I am passing in an array of ints so for example list=[1,2,3] and I want to place c=[0] at location i=2 giving [1,2,0,3]

**Edit2:** As Gustavo pointed out all I needed to do was add c.get(0) for the element location.

```
public List<E> next(List<E> list,List<E> c, int index){
    list.add(index,c);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Could you give a specific example of what you would like to happen given a specific set of input. A test case if you wish.

Comment: I made an edit and added what a test case

Comment: Specific example means we need code.  `[1,2,3]` is not how you declare a list in Java, so we have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @mattm just did that, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am passing in two lists of element E and want to insert one of the lists into the other at a specified index

Your question is not clear:

Do you want to insert the item at `index` from list `c` into `list`?

```
list.add(c.get(index));
```

Do you want to insert the item at `index` from list `c` into `list` at `index`?

```
list.add(index, c.get(index));
```

Based on your edition to the question:

> I am passing in an array of ints so for example list=[1,2,3] and I want to place c=[0] at location i=2 giving [1,2,0,3]

```
list.add(index, c.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide list E in two parts at the index i and then join all 3 lists together in order : E_part1 + c + E_part2

You cannot convert List to element E  - they way you are trying to add would mean that kind of impossible conversion.